# Como cierro un JFrame desde el boton de otro jframe en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Quiero cerrar el jFrame campeones desde el boton de otro Jframe, intente el dispose  y el setVisible y nada no se como se haria, este sería el codigo del boton epro el dispose no funciona como ya dije.

```
 private void jButton_DetallesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
       
        Campeones.dispose();
        new DatosCampeon(Nombrepj).setVisible(true);
        
        
    }
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setVisible` funciona bien, pero necesita que un JFrame pertenezca a otro, el JFrame que desea cerrar debe ser un elemento secundario del JFrame con los botones, o al menos tener un método estático para controlar su visibilidad.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    
    private Ventana2 v2 = new Ventana2(this);
    
    JButton abrir = new JButton("abrir");
    JButton cerrar = new JButton("cerrar");
    
    public Main() {
        crearVentana();
        crearbotones();
    }

    private void crearbotones() {
        abrir.setBounds(10, 20, 150, 30);
        cerrar.setBounds(10, 60, 150, 30);
        
        abrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                v2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        cerrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                v2.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        
        add(abrir);
        add(cerrar);
    }

    private void crearVentana() {
        setSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }
    

}

class Ventana2 extends JFrame {
    public Ventana2(JFrame padre) {
        setVisible(false);
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        setLocationRelativeTo(padre);
    }
}
```